# Can't use async and await on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, async-await, solidity, web3js

Im trying to play [Ethernaut by Zeppelin](https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/) on Firefox but I cant use async and await in the console to interact with the contract.

I tried it in Chrome and Brave and worked fine, also made [this test](http://sole.github.io/test_cases/async_await/) and it said that my browser supports it. Im using Firefox Quantum 63.0.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

[image: the same syntax works in chrome and brave]

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is: you can only use `await` in an `async` function. You can always call the function and save the Promise it returns in a variable.

Comment: Great thanks, I saved it in a  variable and it showed me what I wanted but I still cant understand what the exact same line works on chrome and brave.

Comment: Well the consoles in different browsers have significantly different implementation schemes.